# Bot Framework Composer - failed

Tags: azure, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm trying to build a chatbot and when I click on start bot I get an error.

Error occurred building the bot

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The
> framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found. -
> The following frameworks were found: 5.0.7 at [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] You can resolve the
> problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK. The
> specified framework can be found at: -
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64

I have all of these installed:
[image]

How can I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Just download the 3.1.o version also and it should work.